# How to show an SSRS report in an MVC web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services

I have some reports sitting in a server. I'm now creating a CRUD application in MVC 3 that populates the database that the reports use. I'd like to be able to display the report in a web page as a preview, as well as being able to print them from the front end. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use the [ReportViewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) if you want SSRS features in your page, unless you want to write them yourself.

You can pass data to the control from MVC though, and you can build better parameter handling